# Can't monitor Kickstart post-install log

Tags: centos, rhel, tty, scientific-linux, kickstart

I'm installing Scientific Linux 7 (I've got no reason to this isn't the case with all RHEL forks though) with a Kickstart script that contains the following:

```
%post --interpreter /bin/bash --log /root/postinstall.log
# do stuff
%end
```

After install, the log file is there for inspection as expected.

But, using SL 6 I used to be able to change to TTY 2 and watch the log with `tail -f /mnt/sysimage/root/postinstall.log`. Now, it appears the log is created, but contents are not written until the post-install process is completed.

Is there a way to monitor this progress? I've looked for the log file in `/tmp/`, `/var/log/`, `/mnt/sysimage/tmp/`, and `/mnt/sysimage/var/log/` without any luck. If the log file isn't available, is there a way to send output to another TTY from a Kickstart post-install script?

**Attempt 1:**

```
%post --interpreter /bin/bash
(
# do stuff
echo foo
echo bar
echo baz
) | tee /root/postinstall.log > /dev/tty1
%end
```

This almost works, however, line endings seem to be a problem. It's only doing an LF, not a CR on the screen. The above outputs this on TTY1:

```
foo
    bar
        baz
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
%post --interpreter /bin/bash --log /root/postinstall.log

echo "Changing output to TTY 3; press Alt-F3 to view" > /dev/tty1
exec 1>/dev/tty3 2>&1
#do stuff
%end
```

This outputs the data correctly to the screen, but logs nothing. It also has the curious side-effect of delaying the reboot for like 10 minutes after the script completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out:

```
%post --interpreter /bin/bash

printf "Changing output to TTY 3; press Alt-F3 to view\r\n" > /dev/tty1
{
# do stuff
} 2>&1 | tee /root/postinstall.log > /dev/tty3

%end
```

As mentioned in the question, the screen on `/dev/tty1` seems to have problems with line endings, so my first attempt probably would have worked had I redirected to `/dev/tty3` instead. But this solution avoids the subshell and also redirects STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your output to /dev/pts/0 instead.

Comment: Yes, `/dev/pts/0` seems to handle line endings much better than `/dev/tty1`.

Comment: `/dev/pts/0` doesn't work on EL8 or EL9 . . This special file is only available outside of the chroot.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec < /dev/tty6 > /dev/tty6
chvt 6
<scripts here>
chvt 1
```

This worked for me, I can monitor the %post without having to flip ttys

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with carriage return if you use

```
echo "message" >/dev/tty1
```

Try instead

```
echo -e "message\r" >/dev/tty1
```